The configuration space of 3 unordered points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with distinct distances
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $A_n(X) = \{ (x_i)_{i=1}^n \in X^n \mid \forall i \neq j: x_i \neq x_j \}$ to be the space of $n$ ordered distinct points in $X$. Define $B_n(X) = \{ (x_i)_{i=1}^n \in A_n(X) \mid \forall \{i, j\} \neq \{k, l\}: d(x_i, x_j) \neq d(x_k, x_l) \}$ to be the space of $n$ ordered distinct points in $X$ with distinct distances. Define $C_n(X) = B_n(X)/S_n$ to be the space of $n$ unordered distinct points in $X$ with distinct distances.
I'm trying to understand the space $C_n(X)$ in the smallest nontrivial case I could think of: $n = 3$ and $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. So, how can we describe $C_3(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the space of $3$ unordered distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with distinct distances, up to homeomorphism? What is its homotopy type?

After playing around with it in GeoGebra I'd conjecture that the homotopy type is $S^1$.

The target of this answer is to provide a certain understanding of the "configuration space" of triangles with side lengths $(a,b,c)$ (with $a,b,c >0$) :
For any such triple $(a,b,c)$, there exists an alternative representation $(u,v,w)$, (with $u,v,w>0$) such that :
$$\begin{cases}a&=&&&v&+&w\\
b&=&u&&&+&w\\
c&=&u&+&v&&\\\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
with a geometrical interpretation of $u,v,w$) that can be seen on Fig. 1

Fig.1 $u,v,w$ can be interpreted as the radii of mutually tangent circles centered in $A,B,C$ resp, all of them orthogonal to the incircle.
(1) can be written under the form :
$$\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0} \pmatrix{u\\v\\w} \ \iff \ \pmatrix{u\\v\\w}=\tfrac12 \pmatrix{-1&1&1\\1&-1&1\\1&1&-1}\pmatrix{a\\b\\c} \tag{2}$$
As a consequence of (2), $u,v,w$ are positive due to triangle inequalities that can be written under the following form :
$$\begin{cases}(b+c)-a=2u > 0\\(c+a)-b=2v > 0\\(a+b)-c=2w > 0\end{cases}\tag{3}$$
Besides, (1) can be written in the following way :
$$\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}=u \pmatrix{0\\1\\1}+v \pmatrix{1\\0\\1}+w \pmatrix{1\\1\\0},\tag{4}$$
which means that the set of triangles can be represented wrt coordinates $a,b,c$ as
$$\text{the convex hull of half-lines} \ \ \mathbb{R}^+ \pmatrix{0\\1\\1}, \ \ \ \ \mathbb{R}^+ \pmatrix{1\\0\\1}, \ \ \ \ \mathbb{R}^+ \pmatrix{1\\1\\0}\tag{5}$$

Let us retrieve this result in a different manner.
Let us consider the Cayley-Menger determinant :
$$16\Delta ^{2}=\begin{vmatrix}0&1&1&1\\1&0&c^{2}&b^{2}\\1&c^{2}&0&a^{2}\\1&b^{2}&a^{2}&0\\\end{vmatrix} > 0 \tag{6}$$
where $\Delta$ is the area of the triangle.
In the present low-dimensional case, (6) is nothing else than Heron's formula
$$16 \Delta^2=(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)\tag{7}$$
or, in terms of variables $u,v,w$, under the more compact form :
$$\Delta^2=(u+v+w)uvw\tag{8}$$
Expressing the positivity of product (7) is equivalent to say that the valid points are those already found in the first part : generic point $(a,b,c)$ must be on a certain side of three different planes, which amounts to say that it must belong to the  non-bounded wedge-form volume whose truncation appears as a tetrahedron on Fig. 2.

Fig. 2.
Remark : the interest of Cayley-Menger expression is that it can be extended to any dimensions.

See this nice article

See also this video

And the very nicely illustrated big article on triangle stacks.

Equations (1) are sometimes called "Ravi's substitution".

We may as well spend the $S_3$-action to identify $C_3(X)$ with the subset of triples $({\bf x}, {\bf y}, {\bf z}) \in B_3(X)$ for which
$$d(y,z) < d(z, x) < d(x,y)$$
This approach is specific to $n = 3$, since for other $n$ there is no bijection between points and pairs of points.
Now specialize to $X = \Bbb R^m$, $m > 1$, in which setting the problem can be interpreted as asking for the configuration space of scalene triangles in $\Bbb R^m$. The translation $C_3(\Bbb R^m) \to C_3(\Bbb R^m)$,
$$({\bf x}, {\bf y}, {\bf z}) \mapsto ({\bf x} - {\bf z}, {\bf y} - {\bf z}, {\bf 0})$$ translates each scalene triangle so that the vertex opposite its longest side sits at the origin. Since it preserves distances between components and, it yields a homeomorphism
\begin{multline*}
C_3(\Bbb R^m) \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \Bbb R^m \times \{({\bf x}', {\bf y}') \in (\Bbb R^m)^2 \mid ({\bf x}', {\bf y}', {\bf 0}) \in C_3(\Bbb R^m)\}), \\
({\bf x}, {\bf y}, {\bf z}) \mapsto ({\bf z}, ({\bf x} - {\bf z}, {\bf y} - {\bf z})) .
\end{multline*}
But the sides $\overline{{\bf 0}{\bf x}'}$ and $\overline{{\bf 0}{\bf y}'}$ of the translated triangle respectively have lengths $|{\bf x}'|$ and $|{\bf y}'|$, so the second factor of the above product is just
$$\mathcal C := \{({\bf x}', {\bf y}') \in (\Bbb R^m)^2 \mid {\bf x}', {\bf y}' \in \Bbb R^m, |{\bf x}'| > |{\bf y}'|\},$$ which is the open cone of spacelike elements in $(\Bbb R^m)^2 \cong \Bbb R^{2 m}$ associated to the (indefinite) inner product (of signature $(m, m)$) characterized by $$||({\bf x}', {\bf y}')||^2 := |{\bf x}'|^2 - |{\bf y}'|^2 .$$
Via the map $({\bf x}', {\bf y}') \mapsto \left(\log ||({\bf x}', {\bf y}')|| , \frac{({\bf x}', {\bf y}')}{||({\bf x}', {\bf y}')||} \right)$ we can identify $\mathcal C \cong \Bbb R \times AdS_{m - 1, m}$, where the second factor is the anti-de Sitter space of signature $(m - 1, m)$, giving a homeomorphism
$$C_3(\Bbb R^m) \cong \Bbb R^{m + 1} \times AdS_{m - 1, m} .$$
If the special case $m = 2$ (so, the configuration space of scalene triangles in the plane), $C \cong \Bbb R \times AdS_3$, where the second factor is $3$-dimensional (anti-)de Sitter space, which in turn is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb S^1$. So, concatenating our identifications yields a homeomorphism
$$\boxed{C_3(\Bbb R^2) \cong \Bbb R^5 \times S^1} ,$$
which induces a homotopy equivalence $$\boxed{C_3(\Bbb R^2) \simeq S^1} ,$$ in agreement with Naïm Favier's conjecture in the comments..
